# C-program that searches through an array to find a sequence of characters

Tags: c, arrays, function, for-loop, do-while

I am just a beginner in C programming. Please help me in the following question.

Question:A program that searches through a given array that contains a sequence of characters. These characters are restricted to be the letters A, G, T, or C. The last character in the sequence is set to be the code 0, so that the end is easily detected.

Can't find what am I doing wrong here, but keep getting error.

```
/*A program that searches through a given array that contains a sequence of characters. These characters are restricted 
to be the letters A, G, T, or C. The last character in the sequence is set to be the code 0, so that the end is easily
detected. That array should be declared and initialized.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
void input_sequence(int length,char input[]);
void search(char C[],char DNA[],int length);

int main(void) {
    //Given array
    char DNA[] = {'A', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'C', 
          'C', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', 
          'A', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 
          'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'A', 
          'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 
          'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'T', 
          'C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 
          'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 
          'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', '\0'};
    int length,i=0,k;
    /*Program should repeatedly ask the user for two things: the length of a search sequence,
    and the search sequence itself*/
    /*The program should terminate when the length of the input sequence is zero or less*/
    do{
        printf("Enter length of DNA sequence to match: ");
        scanf("%d",&length);
        Search sequence array
        char input[length];
        //input sequence length has to be >0
        if(length>0){
            input_sequence(length,input[]);
            /*The elements of the search sequence may take on one of five characters: A,G,T,C and *. The
            meaning of the ‘*’ character is that it matches all four nucleotides: A,G,T and C.*/
            for(i=0; i<length; i++){
                k=0;
                if(input[i]!='A'&&input[i]!='G'&&input[i]!='T'&&input[i]!='C'&&input[i]!='*'){
                    printf("Erroneous character input ’%c’ exiting\n",input[i]);
                    k=1;
                }
                if(k==1)
                    break;             
            }
            if(k==0){
                search(input,DNA,length);
            }
            k=0;
        }
    }
    while(length>0);
    printf("Goodbye");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

//Function to search for input sequence in the given array
void search(char C[],char DNA[],int length){
    int numFound = 0,i,foundIndex;
    bool found = false;
    for(i=0;i<length && !found;i++) {
        int n=0;
        char temp=C[i];
        if (temp==DNA[i]) {
            numFound++;
            if (numFound == length) {
                found = true;
                foundIndex = i - (length-1);
            }
        }
        else numFound = 0;
    }
    if (found)
        printf("Match of search sequence found at element %d\n",foundIndex);   
}

void input_sequence(int length,char input[]){
    int i;
    printf("Enter %d characters (one of AGTC*) as a search sequence: ",length);
    for(i=0; i<length; i++){
        scanf(" %c", &input[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please press Ctrl+A and Delete and start over. The nested `if` statements are really a mess, no one would do it like that. Also, WHAT IS THE QUESTION?

Comment: Question: A program that searches through a given array that contains a sequence of characters. These characters are restricted to be the letters A, G, T, or C. The last character in the sequence is set to be the code 0, so that the end is easily detected.

Comment: That is not a question to me, you ask here if you have a problem and want to fix it.

Comment: Search for permutations

Comment: What error are you getting, and I am not surprised, do you understand the code? really, think it through again and try to avoid that kind of nested `if`s.

Comment: Are you looking for `strstr()`?

Comment: The elements of the search sequence may take on one of five characters: A,G,T,C and *. The meaning of the ‘*’ character is that it matches all four nucleotides: A,G,T and C. @iharob

I am not sure if the function "search" can search the input sequence effectively.

Comment: No I can't use any string function, the content hasn't covered yet. @MichaelBurr

Comment: The aim for the nested loop is to check if the user giving any valid input or not @iharob

Comment: It's too complicated, there has to be a better way to do it. Read about [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

Comment: One way, you can simplify the nested if is to change it to 'if(input[i] !='A' && input[i] !='G' ..). Also, in your question, include a description of the problem, what part is not working as expected, errors that you see, etc.

Comment: Inside main function when I call for "search" for, that part is giving me error @Ramana

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token @Ramana

Comment: Change "search(input[],DNA[],length);" to "search(input,DNA,length);"  If you include the line number along with error message, that will help in quickly finding the solution.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix the items raised by the compiler.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: this line: `char input[length];` will be a problem when user inputs 0 or a value <0 or the scanf() fails.   when calling scanf(), always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.   Test the value of `length` before any usage of that value

Comment: after correcting all the compile errors/warnings, the search() function only finds the search string if it is the very first characters in the data[] array.   so that function needs to be re-designed to search the whole data[] array, not just the first few characters.

Answer (score 3):

Here example using [GNU C library regexp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

void search(const char *regexp_str, const char *DNA, int length)
{
    int reti;
    const char *p = DNA;
    const int n_matches = 5;
    regmatch_t m[n_matches];
    regex_t regex;
    (void)length;

    reti = regcomp(&regex, regexp_str, 0);
    if(reti) {
        printf("Could not compile regex: %s\n", regexp_str);
        return;
    }

    while(1) {//based on http://www.lemoda.net/c/unix-regex/
        int nomatch = regexec(&regex, p, n_matches, m, 0);
        if(nomatch) {
            printf ("No more matches.\n");
            return;
        }
        if(m[0].rm_so != -1) {
            int start = m[0].rm_so + (p - DNA);
            int finish = m[0].rm_eo + (p - DNA);
            printf("'%.*s' (bytes %d:%d)\n",
                    m[0].rm_eo - m[0].rm_so, m[0].rm_so + p,
                    start, finish);
        }
        p += m[0].rm_eo;
    }
    regfree(&regex);
}

int main(void) {
    const char *DNA = "AGCGGGACCGTCCCGACATTGATGAAGGGTCATAGACCCA"
                      "ATACGCCACCACCCCAAGTTTTCCTGTGTCTTCCATTGAG"
                      "TAGATTGACACTCCCAGATG";
    while(1) {
        int length;
        char input[256];

        printf("Enter length of DNA sequence to match: ");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        length = strtol(input, NULL, 10);
        if(length <= 0) {//input sequence length has to be >0
            break;
        } else if(length >= (int)(sizeof(input) - 1)) {
            printf("ERROR: Too big length=%d, max supported length=%d\n",
                   length, sizeof(input) - 1);
            break;
        }

        while(1) {
            const char *validInputs = "AGTC*";
            printf("Enter %d characters (one of AGTC*) as a search sequence: ",length);
            fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

            int valid = 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if(strchr(validInputs, input[i]) == NULL) {
                  printf("Erroneous character input '%c' in '%s'\n", input[i], input);
                  valid = 0;
                  break;
                }
            }
            if(valid) {
                break;
            }
        }
        input[length] = 0;
        //substitute '*' on '.' for using in regexp
        char *ptr = input;
        while((ptr = strchr(ptr, '*')) != NULL) {
            *ptr = '.';
        };
        printf("search for: %s\n", input);
        search(input, DNA, length);
    }
    printf("Goodbye\n");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

In additional using C++11 `std::regex` (need to change `search()` only):

```
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

void search(const char *C, const char *DNA, int )
{
    std::regex regex(C);
    std::string str(DNA);
    auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), regex);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();
    printf("Found %d matches:\n", std::distance(words_begin, words_end));
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
        std::smatch match = *i;
        printf(" match: %s, pos=%d\n", match.str().c_str(), match.position());
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, the answer code does not compile.  There are a number of errors and several warnings raised by the compiler (gcc on ubuntu linux 14.04)

Comment: @user3629249 thanks, I fixed errors and warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` in gcc-5.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

In your main function, this line is an issue:

```
search(input[],DNA[],length);
```

Arguments 1 and 2, input[] and DNA[] are incorrect. That notation is used for declaring and initializing arrays. When calling those arrays, you should leave the brackets out unless you want a specific element from that array. 
Try re-writing it as:

```
search(input, DNA, length);
```

Also, you are missing an end curly brace at the end of your do while loop.

Comment: If you could look through my recently edited code please

Comment: This is what the compiler returns: helpComm.c: In function ‘main’:
helpComm.c:30: error: ‘Search’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helpComm.c:34: error: ‘input’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helpComm.c:34: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token
If you go to line 30, you will find you made a comment, but without using the // comment notation. Also, in line 34, you made a similar error to your original post, by including [] brackets.

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea is to scan through the the array, compare chars until you find all match. To implement your can have two pointers, one initially pointing to DNA array and the other pointing to your target array. Then you compare the two chars and move the pointers one step ahead if they match. If the match failed, reset the target array pointer to the first char and move the DNA pointer one step ahead. Restart these procedures until all match.
There is a very efficient algorithm you can take a look, the [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

If you don't want to implement an algorithm yourself, there is a simple built-in function [strstr()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm). You pass the two arrays to it and it will return the first occurrence position.

Comment: Do not post link only answers.